# create initial partition

Tags: 13.10

I have 1 TB hard disk. I have already divided those into 3 partitions, leaving 73GB as unallocated for installing Ubuntu in it. Now when am trying to install the Ubuntu, I have some questions. How should I fill the below mentioned fields:

1. Type of new partition (primary/logical)
2. Use as (Ext4 journaling file system/Ext3/Ext2/ btrfs journaling FS/.../FAT 16,32/swap area)
3. Mount Point `/`, `/boot`, `/home`, `/tmp`, `/usr`, `/var` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of installation when Ubuntu Installation Interface will be prompted , in that choose INSTALL UBUNTU , provide all the details , When it ask for where to install choose **Something Else** , here you have to be very careful , do exactly what I am about to say -

Look at the partion , there will be one named as **FREE SPACE** click on that then click on **+** to split it into usable partition  , then change the size of the partition by scroll down option or enter it manually ,the size should exactly same as the Physicall ram or Double of it and in the format option choose **SWAP AREA** let it be logical and check at the end of SPACE.  till now we are done with creating swap partion.

Next click on **+** again and let the size as it is then check begining of the space and choose partion **EXT4** and in the mount Option choose **/** that is for root partition means everything will be installed in it, and let this to be **LOGICAL**.

Click next and Install it .

Remember both the partitions are **LOGICAL** , swap is at the end of space and root at the beginning ,in swap just select format as SWAP AREA with no mount option and for root Partition choose the partition EXT4 with mount point / .

Hope I have explained exactly what you want.

Comment: But maximum allowed partitions on intel boards is 4 .. since i already have 3 partitions..  i guess i can have only 1 more partition allowed.. (just guessing)

Comment: and i also have another Qn.. does "EXT4" mean "EXT4 journaling file system" ?

Comment: What if i want the file system to be of NTFS type.. i could actually not find any option of that type.. is it possible to change the file system type, atleast later after the installation of the Ubuntu OS ?

Comment: maximum allowed partition is four , HOW?? You can have as many as partition you want , but that will slow down processing on windows not on ubuntu.  Linux just dont support NTFS partition as it only meant for windows . You can mount NTFS partition and use it completely but you can not install ubuntu ON ntfs , well Ext4 is far more advanced as compared to ntfs that means like you dont have to do any defregmentation for making searching copying pasting and processing files fast.

Comment: and yes  ext4 or fourth extended filesystem is the  successor to ext3 is a journaling file system for Linux, and A journaling file system is a file system that keeps track of the changes that will be made in a journal, So EXT4 and EXT4 journalling file system is same..